# Return in method only when outside event handler has been called

Tags: c#, asynchronous

So I want to return in a method only when some asnyc processes (but not with await) has been finshed. What is the best way to block the method procedure and waitint for the event handler. Yes I can do a while loop to block the method and wait for a boolean whichh will be switched when event handler has been called. But I think this can not be the best way?

Comment: It sounds like `async \ await` is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Care to show the *relevant* code. IMO what you are trying to achieve is a bad programming. Ideally, your event handler should do the further processing and not the caller method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for [`ManualResetEventSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class ManualResetEventPlayground
{
    public ManualResetEventPlayground()
    {
        SomeEvent += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Opens the door, blocked code will resume
            Console.WriteLine("Opening the door to let the method return...");
            _resetEvent.Set();
        };

        Task.Run(() => MethodThatMustWaitUntilSomeEventIsFired());
        Task.Run(() => MethodThatFiresTheEvent());
    }

    private event EventHandler SomeEvent;
    private static readonly ManualResetEventSlim _resetEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);


    public string MethodThatMustWaitUntilSomeEventIsFired()
    {
        // Some stuff to do before blocking

        try
        {
            // This will block this thread until
            // the event is fired and opens the door
            Console.WriteLine("Blocking the thread calling the method");
            _resetEvent.Wait();
        }
        finally
        {
            _resetEvent.Reset();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Now this method can be returned!");

        return "finished";
    }
    public void MethodThatFiresTheEvent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Firing the event...");

        if (SomeEvent != null) SomeEvent(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

If you instantiate this class on a Console application you'll get the following output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `async Task` methods will return you a `Task<Result>` object and you can simply call `task.Wait();`.

```
var task = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://google.com");
task.Wait();

Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
```

Comment: You do not need task.Wait() here as task.Result blocks the calling thread until the async operation is complete.

Comment: Also, using `task.Wait` or a blocking `task.Result` should be avoided, use `async/await` instead.

Comment: Yes, that would be a way, but I do not have a task in the youtube extractor lib which i have to use. Your solution is working with the WebClient...

Answer (score 0):

Well if you really don't want to use async/await then Monitor is your choice.

In the main thread:

```
// To wait for a signal from another thread
Monitor.Wait(SyncRoot);
```

In working thread:

```
Monitor.Pulse(SyncRoot);
```

SyncRoot is any object.